# How to access a page that is administered by a user?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am using Facebook api in my application.  And I need to access posts on a page that the user administers.  Is it possible to get this without a user token if the user has previously allowed my app access to that page?

Comment: You should be using a page access token for that in the first place.

Comment: how can I get the page token?  Do I need a user token for this?

Comment: Yes, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/guides/access-tokens#pagetokens

Comment: Is it possible to get open content from a page without using a user token?  Through the application's secret key, if the user gave access earlier?  I need the user to log in to one service and receive the content on another, but I want to avoid storing tokens

Comment: No, you can not use the app access token to access page content.